# Jquery cycle plugin not pausing

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have an interesting issue... I created a featured content slider that triggers a sub slideshow for each slide...  Everything works as expected except the pause on the pagers. I've tried the native options as well as binding a hover event to the pager. Any help would be appreciated.

function subCycle(){

```
$("#inside-tabs").html("");

$('#' + this.id + ' ul').cycle({ 
    fx:     'fade',
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout: 3000,
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
    pager:  '#inside-tabs',
    allowPagerClickBubble: true,
    pause: 1,
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
        var link = $('#' + slide.id + ' h4 a').attr("href");
            return '<li><a href="'+ link +'">' + slide.title + '</a></li>'; 
        }
  });
```

}

```
$('#page-banner ul').cycle({
    before: subCycle,
    slideExpr: '.parent-page',
    fx:     'fade', 
    speed:  'fast',
    timeout: 9000,
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover', 
    pager:  '#outside-tabs',
    allowPagerClickBubble: true,
    pause: 1,
    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) { 
           var link = $('#' + slide.id + ' h3 a').attr("href");
           return '<li><a href="'+ link +'">' + slide.title + '</a></li>';
        }
});
```

Comment: you aren't calling pause in any of your other events are you? once you start to mess with the pause state manually things can get messed. kind of hard to debug this here. A working example somewhere would be nice =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was resolved... The solution was

```
$('#your_pager li a').live('hover', function() { 
  $('#container ul').cycle('toggle'); 
});
```